# tkinter- setting grid's column weight

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to change the grid's column weight and just cant do it.
im tryinng to make a tic tac toe game and i cant set up the frames.

i want to make 9 frames for each block on the screen, that each one that will be clicked will set a different shape, you know the game ;)

[image: image of the game].

im trying to change the column weight by using `grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)` but still not working.

would appreciate any help, thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def intro():
    global intro
    intro= Tk()
    intro.geometry("300x250+710+290")
    canvas = Canvas(intro, width=300,height=250)
    canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
    filename = PhotoImage(file="rsz_2000px-tic_tac_toesvg.png")
    canvas.create_image(245,210, image=filename)
    titlename= PhotoImage(file="rsz_1coollogo_com-141061778_1.png")
    canvas.create_image(150,25,image=titlename)
    playb= Button(canvas,text="PLAY",command=game)
    exitb= Button(canvas,text="QUIT",command=quit)
    infolabel= Label(canvas,text="©moti de gever made this",fg="RED")
    playb.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
    exitb.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.61,anchor=CENTER)
    infolabel.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.95,anchor=CENTER)

    intro.mainloop()

def quit():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("exit?","are you sure you want to exit?"):
        intro.destroy()

def game():
    intro.destroy()
    game=Tk()
    game.geometry("300x250+710+290")
    canvas= Canvas(game, width=300,height=250)
    canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
    game.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    canvas.create_line(105,0,105,250,width=5)
    canvas.create_line(210, 0, 210, 250, width=5)
    canvas.create_line(0, 85, 300, 85, width=5)
    canvas.create_line(0, 170, 300, 170, width=5)
    frameA= Frame(game,height=83,width=103,bg="BLUE")
    frameA.grid(row=0,column=0)
    #frameA.bind("<Button-1>",test)
    frameB = Frame(game, height=83, width=103,bg="RED")
    frameB.grid(row=0, column=1)
    frameB.bind("<Button-1>", test)

def test(event):
    print("working")




intro()
```

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: `grid()` (and `place()`/`pack()`) is used to put widgets in other widgets but not in `Canvas`. If you have images in wrong places then you have to move them.

Comment: Please provide [a _Minimal_, _Complete_, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `intro` is both redundant, making the code un-minimalistic, and it also makes the code incomplete as not everyone necessarily has `"rsz_1coollogo_com-141061778_1.png"`.

Comment: maybe use `create_window()` to put `Frame` on `Canvas`. BTW: rather you shouldn't use `grid()` and `place()` in the same window or frame. `grid()` try to calculate position based on existign widgets, if you use `place()` then `grid()` may have problem co calculate positions.

Comment: Essentially I don't think you'd want `Frame` and `Canvas` as siblings to same parent `Tk`. You probably want to have `Frame` as a child _to_ `Canvas`.

Comment: You have 2 Tk() instances, intro= Tk() and game=Tk(), which can cause problems, and calling grid on a Tk() instance i.e. a new window, is not done because there is nothing to grid a new window into.  Use Toplevel instead of the 2nd instance.  And there is a function named game() and a Tk instance named game which is confusting. Also give columnconfigure a minsize.

Answer (score 0):

The line `game.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)` *does* work as it makes the 0th column in `game`'s grid(which has `frameA` in it) resize as proportionally(`weight=1`) to its parent, `game`.

Now `frameA` is not proportionally resizing, but it is *allowed to* do so, it is given extra space which it just doesn't use. Try setting its `sticky` option as well:

```
frameA.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

with that, it is both allowed to resize *horizontally*(`grid_columnconfigure`), and it also uses what it is allowed to, up to a maximum on all sides (`sticky='nsew'`).

Comment: you have an extra backtick (\`) around `sticky='nsew'`

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the feedback, edited to fix.